# is there any @types for interoperable browser extension object?

Tags: typescript, types, cross-browser, browser-extension

I'm creating a browser extension that would be compatible in **Edge**, **Chrome**, and **Firefox** using Typescript.

I have found an article that discusses interopable browser extension that has a sample of this code:

```
window.browser = (function () {
  return window.msBrowser ||
    window.browser ||
    window.chrome;
})();
```

So I was planning to create a Browser class and initialize a property depending what browser the extension is sitting. Something like the below codes:

```
export class Browser {
    constructor() {}

    public _browser: object = null;
    get browser() : object {
        if (typeof window.chrome !== 'undefined') {
            this._browser = window.chrome;
        }

        if (typeof window.browser !== 'undefined') {
            this._browser = window.browser;
        }
        return this._browser;
    }
}
```

I was able to add @types/chrome for chrome definition so that I would not throw an exception, however, I could not find any types for `browser` and `msBrowser` object definition. Or any suggestion I can use to do this without getting an error in Typescript.

So my question is there any type definitions I can use to support the `browser`  or `msBrowser` object?

Comment: Why not just use the chrome namespace throughout and set the namespace accordingly based on browser/chrome/ms browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WebExtensions](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebExtensions) seem like the best choice for cross-browser extension development. The most popular type file I can find for the WebExtensions API seems to be https://github.com/kelseasy/web-ext-types. I hope that's helpful.